# 32-bit VMWare on a 64-bit system for a 64-bit VM instance

Tags: 32-bit

I recently bought a 64-bit machine running on Windows 7 64-bit. I already have a 32-bit version software of VMware Workstation 7. I would like to install and run Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit as a VM Instance on my 64-bit Win-7 machine for learning. Will i still be able to use the 32-bit VMWare software to do this or do i have to buy the 64-bit version of VMware Workstation 8?

I ask this because the software is pretty expensive for me.

Please advise.

Comment: My understanding is that the VMware 7.x installer for Windows includes both the 32-bit and 64-bit installations - it's not a separate download. VMware will support 64-bit guests on 32-bit or 64-bit hosts as long as the CPU has the necessary virtualization extensions.  There's a utility on the VMware site that will let you know if your system will support a 64-bit guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont use 32 bit VMWare for 64Bit guest. You have to buy VMWare 64Bit or you can use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) from Oracle for free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I installed OVB and the OVM instances work just fine. I haven't seen all the functionality that was available in VMWare but this was a great replacement for 64-bit machines.